# Mathematical Programming Community

Tags: linear-programming

Is there a good online community for discussing optimization models?  The ones I have found don't seem to have a critical mass for active discussions.

Comment: Have you tried the OR Exchange? http://www.or-exchange.com/

Comment: that website seems to be not that active, and has very few users. also it seems their LaTeX support is missing (if I am not wrong!)